# read data from file with mutual exclusion property

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutual-exclusion

[cpp program](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AlIbg0SkHep3hh7cDKHB00I5oMdq)

I am trying to read all files of a directory and count total number of vowels in them as output through mutual exclusion property. But I am facing some problem here, which I can not identify.

How to compile is mentioned in the first line of cpp program code.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOP8y.png)

Comment: Please, share your code here and your errors. And check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question.

Comment: "cpp program" has the link for source code and "output" is for output image

Comment: In output part the file name read has been trimmed, don't know why. will be thankful for your help sir.